# C++ Multiple definitions error

Tags: c++, multiple-definition-error

I'm getting a bunch of errors for a simple c++ hello world program.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[image: errors]

All the solutions iv'e seen for this were just confusing and didn't help. Im using the Code Blocks IDE.

Comment: Can you upgrade your Code Blocks? Might be a bug

http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=2061.5;wap2

Comment: This is the first real answer iv'e gotten today. thank you.

Comment: Didn't actually fix anything.

Comment: Why "WinMain..."? What kind of project did you set up with Code::Blocks? You should be working with a console application, right?

Comment: Yeah i am. i reinstalled code::blocks twice, and it just doesn't work. It's literally just a simple hello world program. I don't understand whats breaking

Comment: Can you please update your question with the actual compile command that is being used by Code::Blocks? This is a linking error, maybe you're linking with two libraries that implement the same functions. Also, are you sure your program is calling 'g++' instead of 'gcc'? Does your file ends with .c or with .cpp/.cc? Please provide more information and please post the error messages in a place where we can see them in full.